# specifying vscode tasks.json location

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I press F9 in vscode it runs a task from `C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\tasks.json`

That is, no matter what folder or workspace I have open, the same task.json file is always used.

How do I get vscode to use a task.json that is specific to the open workspace or folder?

The docs say that the tasks.json file should be in .vscode/ and I have placed it there, but it is ignored.  I guess I accidently modified a setting that controls where this file should be, but I cannot find it to undo the change.

Clicking menu `Terminal | Configure tasks` also takes me to `C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\tasks.json`

Comment: put the `tasks.json` file in the `.vscode` folder in the workspace

Comment: @rioV8  I have done that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround.

- Delete `C:\Users\James\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\tasks.json`
- Create new workspace
- Clicking menu Terminal | Configure tasks